# Regex extract class path from string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract class path from string. The string format can contain different class paths

(string example: `DEBUG(tab)a.b.c.d.classname#`, `INFO(tab)a.classname#`)

The regex I have:

if there's multiple dots in path `(?:\w\.\w\.[^#]*)` which works fine, but when I add `|(?:[^\d]\w\.\w{1,9999}[^#]*)` if there is class path containing one dot (second example above) it selects tab aswell. Basically I want to make a regex that matches any class path. How to select the path if there is only one dot in the class path?

full string example:

`2019-01-01 01:01:01.000+0000 [id=1](tab_here)INFO(tab_here)a.package.classname#sometext: somemoretext`

so far how regex looks like:

`(?:\w\.\w\.[^#]*)|(?:[^\d]\w\.\w{1,9999}[^#]*)`

UPDATE

the result I want is a class path match without `tab` when it contains only one `dot`:
[the result I have with tab..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7kHy.png)

UPDATE #2:

All answers are great, but I had to modified Vincents one to achive what I wanted. Final regex is

`(\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(?=#)`

wanted without anything in front and in the back. Result is the same as Vincent's output.

Thanks all who participated!

Comment: I don't understand what output you're trying to get. What's missing in your question is a clear example of an input with the expected output. You have provided some inputs example, but what output do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution like this:

`\t([\w\.]+?)#`

This would cover the case you have mentioned. However this might require certain improvements to cover all the possible classpaths"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could match a tab and use a capturing group matching 1+ word chars and repeat that repeated by a dot followed by matching a `#`.

That will prevent matching for example `.#` or    `.#`

If the tab is not required, you can omit it.

```
\t(\w+(?:\.\w+)+)#
```

- `\t` Match a tab
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\.\w+)+` Match 1+ times a dot and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group
- `#` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BBkvPp/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something but I think it's a lot easier than what you have done.

This works for me:

Replacing `.*?([\w\.]+)#.*` with `$1`

Sure it would match patterns like 2 consecutive dots, which are not valid classpaths, but it won't ever happen in your input log, so why bother with complexity?

Testing with javascript in Chrome console:

```
console.log("INFO   a.package.classname#sometext".replace(/.*?([\w\.]+)#.*/,"$1"))
console.log("DEBUG(tab)a.b.c.d.classname#,sometext".replace(/.*?([\w\.]+)#.*/,"$1"))
console.log("INFO(tab)a.classname#,sometext".replace(/.*?([\w\.]+)#.*/,"$1"))
```

Output:

```
a.package.classname
a.b.c.d.classname
a.classname
```

`.*?([\w\.]+)#.*` means any sequence of letters and dots that ends with # (the `.*?` before and `.*` after allows matching everything before and after that pattern to be able to remove it)